# Error in setState while trying to update bookings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Inside the deleteBaseBooking function, I want to set this.state.checkIndexStatus[key] = null using setstate. However, it is giving an error:

```
deleteBaseBookings(){
        for(var key in this.state.checkIndexStatus){
            if(this.state.checkIndexStatus[key]){
                ids.push(key)
                this.updateState(key)
                console.log(ids);
            }
        }
    }

updateState = (key) => {
        this.setState({
            this.state.checkIndexStatus[key] = null
        })
    }
```

I need to update the checkIndexStatus[key] = null , so that it takes null next time and previous IDs will be deleted

Comment: Can you also post the error here?

Comment: Can you add some more context to the question?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb , hi , error is :- Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: this is a reserved word

Comment: please Edit your code and send all of your code in this component

Answer (score 1):

### I think you have syntax Error

You must use `:` instead of `=` in setState
you've use a name that is for react or Js you must change your word's name

```
 deleteBaseBookings(){
            for(var key in this.state.checkIndexStatus){
                if(this.state.checkIndexStatus[key]){
                    ids.push(key)
                    this.updateState(key)
                    console.log(ids);
                }
            }
        }

    updateState = (key) => {
            this.setState({
                this.state.checkIndexStatus[key] : null
            })
        }
```

Comment: i tried, i am getting :- main.js:183430 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: this is a reserved word

Comment: Post your main.js here